# Registering nested objects with React Hook Form

Tags: reactjs, object, react-hook-form

I have been working with RHF for a while and it helps a lot actually, but I have been trying to do something for what I have not enough knowledge maybe.

So the thing its that I have a nested object that I bring to my componen throw props

```
const Child = ({ globalObject, register }) => {
    const renderNested = Object.entries(globalObject.nestedObject);
    

    return (
                        <span>
                            {renderNested.map(([key, value], index) => {
                                return (
                                    <div key={index}>
                                        <Field
                                            type="text"
                                            label={key}
                                            name{`nestedObject.${key}`}
                                            defaultValue={value}
                                            ref={register}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                );
                            })}
                        </span>

    );
};
```

All good, now, one of the keys inside this nestedObject has another object as a value, for which when I map over them and display, the field will show: [object Object]
I know how I would solve that issue if I am using a useState, for example.
Not sure if its a good practice but I would go with something like:

```
defaultValue={typeof value === 'someKey' ? value[key] : value}
```

but in this case using register (which I want to use since it saved me from other nightmares) I am not sure how to solve this.
Should I filter the array outside and then render for one side the keys that dont have an object as a value and then the rest?
It looks to me like it has to be something better than that.
Can anyone give advices?

just to clarify, nestedObject looks like:

```
nestedObject: {
key: value
key: {key:value}
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can access the fields using `.` dot notation, as per documentation for the [register](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register#registerRef) method. So `register("name.key")` works to retrieve the nested object as well as arrays, however note that in React Hook Form v7 the [syntax to retrieve nested array items changed](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#changes-16) from `arrayName[0]` to `arrayName.0`.

Your component would look similar to the following:

```js
const Child = ({ globalObject, register }) => {
  const nestedKeys = Object.keys(globalObject.nestedObject);

  return (
    <>
      {nestedKeys.map((key) => (
        <Field key={key} {...register(`nestedObject.${key}`)} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

You [should not use index as key prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) in this case, as you have another stable identifier for each array element which comes from unique nested object keys.